# JSF - possible to get bounded parent object of inputText value?

Tags: jsf-2

let's say I have an inputText like so:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.stringProperty}" />
```

I would like to modify the renderer so that if the component is bounded to a bean implementing a certain inferface I would like to do render some extra things. But getValue only gets me the stringProperty, is it possible to access the bean as well?

Answer (score 0):

1. I am assuming that you are overriding the renderer for the target component family.
2. In your custom renderer code you can invoke component.getValueExpression() (as defined by UIComponent).
3. Once you have the ValueExpression you can parse it to figure out the parent object that returns the string property.

The down side of this approach is that you are making an assumption that the class containing the stringProperty method **is** the class that should implement the *decorator* interface that you are looking for.

An alternate approach could be that you add a custom attribute (f:attribute) to each input component, which you can fetch in the renderer.

Hope that helps.